# Property 'genre_name' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**File Detail.tsx **

```
interface Detail {
  genre: Detail;
 
}      
<div className="font-mono flex flex-wrap py-2 gap-1">
                    {data?.genre_list.map((genre: Detail, key: number) => (
                      <p key={key}>{genre?.genre_name} ,</p>
                    ))}
                  </div>
```

**File Model.ts **

```
export interface Detail {
  author: string;
  chapter: string[];
  genre_list: string[];
  status: string;
  synopsis: string;
  thumb: string;
  title: string;
  type: string;
  genre_name: string;
}
```

Property 'genre_name' does not exist on type 'string', even though I have typed it on the interface

Answer (score 0):

Use another name for interface in `Detail.tsx`

```js
...

import {Detail} from "./Model"

interface Props {
    genre: Detail
}

...
```

• But i recommend you to use suitable names for objects like `genre: Genre`